Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports while importing ImageDataGenerator
Problem Statement:
I encountered several issues when trying to import Keras components in my TensorFlow project. Initially, I used the following import statements:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

However, I kept getting these errors in VS Code with Pylance:

Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImport
Import "keras.preprocessing" could not be resolved PylancereportMissingImport
Even though TensorFlow and Keras were installed correctly, these errors persisted.

Solution: After some research and experimentation, I found the correct import paths that resolved the issue for both ImageDataGenerator and the Keras callbacks.
For ImageDataGenerator: Instead of using the usual import path:
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

I used:
from keras._tf_keras.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

This path worked perfectly in my environment, and Pylance no longer showed any missing import errors.

I'm using TensorFlow 2.17.0 and Keras 3.5.0 installed via pip install tensorflow.
My IDE is Visual Studio Code, and these errors seemed to be specific to Pylance’s handling of the imports.
If you're facing similar issues, check the import paths in your setup, as they may differ depending on the versions of TensorFlow and Keras you are using.


Consider [edit]ing and answering your question to match the format of a self-answered question.

See can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)
